# JUpload issue on jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, applet, jupload

Im getting:

```
load: class wjhk.jupload2/JUploadApplet.class not found.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: wjhk.jupload2.JUploadApplet.class
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: open HTTP connection failed:http://test1/EAMAPP84/data/docuploads/ROADS/NoamTest/wjhk/jupload2/JUploadApplet/class.class
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.getBytes(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
... 9 more
Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: wjhk.jupload2.JUploadApplet.class
```

on the java consule.

the applet is called:

```
<applet
code="wjhk.jupload2/JUploadApplet.class"
codebase="\EAMAPP84\data\docuploads\ROADS\NoamTest"
archive="JUpload.jar"
width="650"
height="400">
<param name="actionURL"
value="\\test1\EAMAPP84\data\docuploads\ROADS\NoamTest">
</applet>
```

while the jar is sitting in the given directory.
the wierd thing is, when i create a simple html file using this it works, butwhen using it in my jsp page i get this error.

anyone?

Answer (score 0):

The `code` attribute should point to the [fully qualified name](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#25430) of the class (the same as you would use in `import` statement of a normal Java class).

```
code="wjhk.jupload2.JUploadApplet"
```

The exception is by the way also hinting that:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: wjhk.jupload2.JUploadApplet.class
```

*(the `.class` part doesn't belong there at all)*

and also here:

```
java.io.IOException: open HTTP connection failed:http://test1/EAMAPP84
/data/docuploads/ROADS/NoamTest/wjhk/jupload2/JUploadApplet/class.class
```

*(note the `/class.class` part which is obviously wrong)*

Answer (score 0):

```
code="wjhk.jupload2/JUploadApplet.class"
```

Should probably be..

```
code="wjhk.jupload2.JUploadApplet"
```